# Arduino PWM Frequency - Pros and Cons of Modifying

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, analogwrite

I am interested in using an Arduino Uno to produce an analog signal by running PWM through an RC low-pass filter.

I'll be controlling a highly dynamic object and need a clean voltage signal to avoid instabilities.  Per [this calculator on RC designs](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/PWMtool.php), it's suggested that one strategy to reducing voltage ripple is to increase the PWM frequency.

With PWM configured to a default of [980Hz for pins 5 and 6, and PWM of 490Hz for the remaining pins](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/210/why-do-some-pins-have-a-different-pwm-frequency), I've decided that this will create too much voltage ripple for my filter.  I've found [resources](http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Arduino-PWM-Frequency) that describe how to configure the registers to increase the PWM frequency rather drastically.

My question is very simple: Are there any disadvantages to using a higher frequency PWM?  Why is the default set to be so slow?

Thank you!

Comment: Aside from the clock (if using timer0), the only consequence seems to be in how the components you drive with the PWM handle the frequency. Some might heat up a bit more, and/or jitter less. Burning lasers may yield slightly different results.Ignacio makes a good point about servos, too.

Answer (score 3):

A PWM frequency of 490Hz means a period of approximately 2.041ms. This allows a high period of 2ms, which is the maximum pulse length required by a large number of inexpensive servos. Obviously if your design uses no servos then this is not a consideration.

Timer 0 itself is used for the various Arduino timing functions (`delay()`, `millis()`, etc.), so if you change the frequency used for timer 0 then those functions will no longer have accurate results.

Comment: timer 0 is used for pins 5 and 6. So you better go with pins 9 and 10 (timer 1), or 3 and 11 (timer2), as to not break functions like `delay`, `millis` etc.